# What does ConnectionRefused do?

Tags: python, networking, twisted

This is a method of `DatagramProtocol` class in Twisted. As I understand `UDP` protocol doesn't guarantee that someone is listening on the given port even using `ConnectedDatagramProtocol`.

Can someone explain to me, when this method is called and how I suppose to check if there is someone listening to my transmission using `UDP`?

Comment: They are listening if you get a reply back :D (I'm actually being serious. That's how UDP works.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the datagram socket is connected, it can receive ICMP Port Unreachable messages via the Sockets API, which presumably maps into calling this method. Note that I am not speaking of the TCP connect operation here, but the Sockets connect() method, which can be called on a UDP socket, and which presumably maps into some method in the API you are using.